# C# Custom Type Converter for List of Custom class as Image and string

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, typeconverter

I have a `MultiplineItem` type defined as a set of `Icon` / `Caption` / `Description` fields. `Icon` is a type, `Caption` and `Description` are string fields.

```
public MultiplineItem() { }
public MultiplineItem(Icon icon, string caption, string description) 
{
    this.Icon = icon;
    this.Caption = caption;
    this.Description = description;
}
```

All fields have proper `get` and `set`, I haven't included the code because it is long.

And another class has this property:

```
public List<MultiplineItem> Items
{
    get; set;
}
```

I want to use `Items` with `propertyGrid`. So I need to set a proper `TypeConverter` for this.

How can I define a converter and if needed a type editor?

Comment: Google results two and three for a search on PropertyGrid TypeConverter  -  [Use a type converter with a PropertyGrid control in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/use-a-type-converter-with-a-propertygrid-control-in-c/) and [Creating a custom TypeConverter part 1](http://www.cyotek.com/blog/creating-a-custom-typeconverter-part-1)

Comment: @stuartd thank you for suggestion. But I couldn't understand samples while not same my needs. I wonder if there is a solution at least about my needs. Additionally, I did same kind of works like first link you provided. I think my situation is different. Also tried second one but nothing.

Comment: Have you tried just to select your another class instance in a property grid? It should work, giving you `Items` property with collection editor. If you have other requirements, you need to tell us what they are.

Comment: @IvanStoev When I use collection editor, IDE throws me serialization error. I have serialization declaration above of the Item and also Item has serialization methods. Can you provide me some couple of codes whit my needs?